# How to avoid/stop multiple times printing for same event in AXON 4.0.4

Tags: spring-boot, axon

Issue related to AXON EXTENSION TRACING: `TracingAutoConfiguration.configureEventHandler` method printing same event (i.e. `GenericDomainEventMessage`) in log multiple times from given interceptor `o.a.e.t.OpenTraceHandlerInterceptor`.

How to avoid/stop multiple times printing for same event please suggest
[click here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCHAE.png)

Comment: From your image, I can't say if this is the same event or not. The class is the same because DomainEventMessage is the parent class of all your Domain Events.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple log lines is not per definition wrong. As Lucas also states, the `GenericDomainEventMesasge` is the object which Axon uses (at all times) to wrap your events in. Without doing so, the framework cannot pull apart whether it is dealing with an Event, Command or Query messages to begin with.

Furthermore, as a `TrackingEventProcessor` can run in parallel, with multiple threads, you could see a bunch of loglines going through.

On any note, the given description at this stage is too minimal to deduce where the exact problem arises if it is a problem at all.
Hence, I would like to ask you to provide the following, based on which I/we can update this answer:

- What version of Axon Framework are you using?
- What version of Axon's Tracing Extension are you using?
- What do your Event Handling classes look like?
- Is there any specific configuration in place for these Event Handling classes?